# Crystal report: keep group header and details on the same page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've got group: header and details section in subreport. The problem is: when the group is in the bottom of the page it make the gap - header is in the one page and deteis are in the next one. How to keep together both sections?

I've tried following:

> Group Expert->Options-> Keep Group Together

It doesn't help.

And in this link, method two.

> http://www.microassist.com/tips/crystal-reports-prevent-orphaned-group-header

But it doesn't help too.

Thank you for help.

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26988542/Prevent-pagebreak-between-sections-of-a-crystal-report.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This link that you posted helped me.

http://www.microassist.com/tips/crystal-reports-prevent-orphaned-group-header

Right click the group you don't want to be orphaned and choose change group then a small pop-up window opens, click options then check the Keep Group Together checkbox.

GoodLuck!

Comment: This is rather a workaround than a clean solution, because you need to duplicate the layout etc. – but I confirm it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the main right, right click on the subreport there is an option called Keep Together. This will ensure that the whole of subreport will be printed as a whole

Answer (score 0):

The section export will not do what you are trying to do. Keep a group and detail together. Section export will allow you to keep detail together if you select that on the main and sub detail bands. To keep group together as well as print header on each new page you want to go to Report->Group Export. Right click the group and select options. On options tab select Keep Group Together.